# The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle(InitializingBean)

Tags: spring

I start the spring boot application

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        System.out.println("[MessageSourceConfig] constructed");
        var messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("format");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("[MessageSourceConfig] postConstruct");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        var message = messageSource();
        System.out.println("[MessageSourceConfig] " + message);
    }
}
```

then throw exception
┌──->──┐
|  messageSourceConfig
└──<-──┘

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

Continue I remove @Configuration annotation and add @Component then everything is run ok

Who can explain help me about the flow to construct the bean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to reference `messageSource` bean from inside `MessageSourceConfig` and, *at the same time*, have it create the very same bean. **This** is the circular dependency Spring is complaining about.

Switching from `@Configuration` to `@Component` makes the problem go away, of course, because the `messageSource()` then becomes just a regular method, with `@Bean` annotation being <s>ignored</s>.

(**EDIT** it's effectively ignored for the purpose of your scenario, but see comments)

Why do you feel you need `afterPropertiesSet` at all? If you're inside the `messageSource` method, you're about to obtain a fully usable `ResourceBundleMessageSource` instance. Whatever it is you're planning to do inside `afterPropertiesSet`, you can do inside `messageSource()` already, right after the call to `setBaseNames`.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't ignore the `@Bean` on the method it still applies but it only functions as a factory method. It runs in the so called **lite mode**.